# emberjs - block params for component

Tags: ember.js

If I declare a component like this:

```
<p>
  {{#x-autosuggest source=model destination=tags minChars=0}}
    <img src="img/small_avatar.png" title="{{name}}" class="avatar"/>
  {{/x-autosuggest}}
</p>
```

I want the `name` that field to come from a context I pass using the new block params syntax.  I've tried the code sample below but the context is still the context of the controller and not the argument I pass using `yield` in the component's hbs file.

```
<ul class='selections'>
  {{#each destination as |selection|}}
    <li class="selection">
      <a class="as-close" {{action "removeSelection" selection}}>x</a>
      {{yield selection}}
      {{displayHelper selection searchPath}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

How can pass the `selection` argument so I can set the `name` attribute in the original code snippet?

I've recreated a basic example with this [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/vivasa/4/edit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `as |name|` where you're using your component to get the yielded value.

```
<p>
  {{#x-autosuggest source=model destination=tags minChars=0 as |name|}}
    <img src="img/small_avatar.png" title="{{name}}" class="avatar"/>
  {{/x-autosuggest}}
</p>
```

Comment: That did not work, I've added a jsbin to the question.